# What is the difference between those queries and its working?

Tags: sql, oracle

Take a sample table_name = Mybooks,
if we have to select all the books the query will be like

```
select * from mybooks;
```

So when and why do we need aliasing and make query like

```
select books.* from mybooks books;
```

I dont understand how this works and its use

Comment: the two query are equivalent .. in the second you have an alias for the table name and is useful if you need  all column from the table (but need column alsio for other column )

Comment: @scaisEdge     "need column also for other column"    please explain ?

Comment: .there is a mistake   i mean also for others table ..the second notation is used  for  eg:  select books.*,  u.*  from mybooks as books join user as u on books.key = u.key.. (but this is not your case)

Comment: just see books as a nickname for mybooks. Aliases are useful when you join other tables that have some of the same fieldnames. Which is more concise, `mybadasslongtablename.field1` or `t.field1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias is like renaming that particular use of the table, and the reasons to use one are:

1. Simply use a shorter descriptor
2. You use the same table more than once in a query (you need something to differentiate them)

If you only use one table, you don't need an alias, but nothing prevents you from using one.

Examples:

1. One table, doesn't add value, but you can go with any of these:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM LongTableName

   -- Only if you enjoy typing
   SELECT LongTableName.*
   FROM LongTableName

   SELECT *
   FROM LongTableName t

   SELECT t.*
   FROM LongTableName t
   ```
2. With more than one table:

   ```
   -- Cartesian join or cross join, at least one of the instances requires an alias
   SELECT *
   FROM LongTableName, LongTableName l

   -- You are forced to use the full name to refer to an "un-aliased" table
   SELECT LongTableName.Field, l.Field
   FROM LongTableName, LongTableName l

   -- For any other join, if only one table has an alias, like in the previous case,
   -- you will have to use the full name to refer to the other instance
   SELECT *
   FROM LongTableName
   INNER JOIN LongTableName l ON LongTableName.Field = l.Field

   -- Normally you simply use a short alias for both, like this
   SELECT *
   FROM LongTableName l1
   INNER JOIN LongTableName l2 ON l1.Field = l2.Field

   -- Only selecting some fields
   SELECT l1.PrimaryKey, l1.Field, l2.PrimaryKey, l2.Field
   FROM LongTableName l1
   INNER JOIN LongTableName l2 ON l1.Field = l2.Field
   ```

If in the `SELECT` you want all the fields from all used tables, you can just use the `*` and you are done. But if you need to pick specific fields from several tables, you will really appreciate having aliases.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing together two things. You already got a few good answers about using an alias. However, that's not the only way to write the `select *` in a different way.

Without an alias, you could say `select mybooks.* ...`  -  using the table name, not an alias for it.

In some cases you don't need the table name and you can just use `select *`. However, if you need to add other columns - for example `SYSDATE as DT` you can't do this after `select *`.  You must use `select mybooks.*, SYSDATE as DT ...`  -  no need for alias, but you must prefix `*` with the table name, even if the query only refers to one table.

More often this will happen with analytic functions, like `row_number() over ...`

Answer (score 0):

When you have joins in your query a simple * will result in all fields of all tables included in the join. When using books.* the result will contain only all fields of the books table.

This has nothing to do with aliasing so far, that's another concept where you give a table an alias name so that you can distinguish two tables with the same name.

Both concepts make sense only when you have more complex queries with more than one table.

Comment: i do not have a books table.... still this query works in oracle.... I need to do it this way as to pass it to ResultSet class in Java EE... as otherwise it'll convert it in a read only format

Comment: In the second statement you presented, you gave an alias 'books' to the table named 'mybooks'. That means you can use 'books' or 'mybooks' to access the table originally named mybooks.

Comment: ok .... if can access 'mybooks' from 'books' .... then this should work , select * from books; ..... and why do i need an alias for ?

Comment: When you have complex queries with many tables involved you can come to the point that you need to JOIN the same table twice. Then you need to distinguish those two occurrences of the same table. An alias is the only solution then.
Another, more cosmetic use case is to give short aliases for long table names to improve readability of complex queries.